# Installing OpenVPN in Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation, openvpn

I'm trying to install openvpn in my amazon ec2 instance. I tried the following [site](http://alestic.com/2009/05/openvpn-ec2) for my setup.

In my client side I run the following command :

```
sudo openvpn  --proto tcp-client --remote x.x.x.x.x.x. --port 80  --dev tun1  --secret ovpn.key --redirect-gateway def1 --ifconfig 10.4.0.2 10.4.0.1 --daemon
```

And also the following commands:

```
sudo mv /etc/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf.save
echo "nameserver $Of-My-Ec2-Machine-IP" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```

But once I run this command. And I tried to connect to my internet from the client side. But it fails.

And also doing :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn status
```

Doesn't give any output.

Where I'm making the mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that `--dev tun1` needs to just be `--dev tun`. The whole nameserver thing is a little weird too, try connecting without doing it.

If not, what's the output of OpenVPN when you remove the `--daemon` option, and add `--verb 3`? It will be easier to diagnose from there.

You might also want to put all those options into a config file (one per line, remove the `--`s) and just pass OpenVPN the file name.

[The OpenVPN HOWTO](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) might be a useful aid to start off.